# angular.element not works when class is added through ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

if i add a class to an element through ng-class and try to get the existence of the same class through angular-element, its always returns false.

Please let me know whats wrong with the below code,

html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
<input type="text" ng-class="{'red':required == true}"/>
<button ng-click="add()">click</button>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.red {border: 1px solid #ff0000;}
```

javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){

var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('input'));
$scope.required = false;
$scope.add = function(){
$scope.required = true;
console.log(elem.hasClass('red'));
}    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are checking `.hasClass` inside the callback function, this is executed before angulars [digest cycle](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) starts.

So currently:
1. Button pressed - 2. $scope.add executed - 3. Class is checked - 4. Angulars digest cycle changes class

To solve this setup a $timeout which will move your `console.log` to the bottom of the stack.

**[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f7qew755/)**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller("myController", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){

    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('input'));

    $scope.required = false;
    $scope.add = function(){
        $scope.required = true;
        $timeout(function(){
            console.log(elem, elem.hasClass('red'));
        }, 0);
    }

}]);
```